# Getting file name from POST request in Spray-can

Tags: spray, spray-client

I am using Spray-can to host a REST service to which a user will be able to upload a file. The block of code that listens for incoming requests is given below:

```
def receive: Receive = {
case _: Http.Connected => sender ! Http.Register(self)

case req@HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, Uri.Path("/upload"), headers, entity, _) =>
  logger.info("Received file upload request.")

// Process the uploaded data using the 'entity' object
```

I upload the file using this curl command:

```
curl --data-binary @inputFile.csv 'devserver:8998/upload?tenant=DressShop&facility=CityCenter&customer=Jimmy'
```

The challenge I am facing is that I'm not able to pick up the filename "inputFile.csv" from the request, though I'm getting the data from the "entity" object. I tried poring through the API but couldn't find out any way to get the filename.

My objective is to ensure that I allow upload of only csv files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the entity as form data using `as`

```
as[MultipartFormData]
```

Then you can get the file name from the header fields:

```
    def processFormData(data: MultipartFormData) = {
        var attForm = ""
        val bodyPart = data.fields(0)

        data.fields foreach {
            bodyPart => println(bodyPart.headers.find(h=> h.is("content-disposition")).get.value)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

[image]

The filename can be found in `parameters`.